# Press Enter and the button function to be called

Tags: javascript

I have a page login, with label of user and pass. I want to know, how I do to when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in textbox to the button function to be called.

**Login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#btnOK").on("click", function () {
        var UserName = $("#txt_user").val();
        var Password = $("#txt_pass").val();
               .
               .
               .

});
```

Login.cshtml

```
form action="@Url.Action("Default")" method="post"> 
    <div id="boxLogin">
        <br />
        <label id="lbl_login">Login</label>

        <div id="log">
            <img src="../../img/images.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div class="boxUser">
            <label id="lbl_user">User: </label>
            <input id="txt_user" type="text" value="" name="UserName">
        </div>

        <div class="boxPass">
            <label id="lbl_pass">Pass: </label>
            <input id="txt_pass" type="password" name="Password">
        </div>

        <div id="btns"> 
           <input type="button" ID="btnOK" class="btn" value="Confirm" />       
           <input type="button" ID="btnCancel" class="btn" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Use a submit button and listen for the form submit event instead of the button click event, and it will automatically work for enter keys pressed in the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#txt_senha").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#btnOK").click();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can submit it using below code:

```
$('#txt_usuario').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
     $( "#form" ).submit();
  }
});
```

where form - is your form id.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is to change the `btnOK` element to a submit button (`type="submit"`), and change the javascript to run on the onsubmit event of the form.